# How to connect to a Soap(WSDL) Web Service without using ksoap2 library?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm developing an android application that can connect to a `SOAP` web service. I'm using `ksoap2` but I'm having a hard time with this I saw a lot of blogs and tutorial but no one helped me.

Now I'm looking for another way how to connect and to request in a web service. Can anyone help me with this?

Or can anyone suggest how to connect to a soap(WSDL) web service using `HTTPClient` or `HttpUrlConnection`? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpURLConnection to build the requests yourself.

You basically need to create GET, PUT, POST and DELETE-requests using HttpURLConnection. There are a lot of examples out there for this.
[POST-request](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)

Then you have to create your data.

In case of JSON-data you can use JSONObject.

In case of XML-data you can use a library for creating xml-data (I think SimpleXML may be ok for that) or create the data "by hand" using StringBuilder or something like that.